# How can I check if multiple properties exists on an object without being too verbose?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to verify that some properties exist on a configuration object and have values (truthy? not necessrily as a few pointed out in the comments) in javascript in the following manner:

```
const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
    return options.JanrainAppSettings
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.tokenUrl
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture.clientId
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture.appId
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture.appDomain
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture.captureServer
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.httpLoadUrl
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.httpsLoadUrl
}
```

I feel this is too verbose and I am curious if there is a better pattern. Perhaps something like
`if (['my', 'options'] in  myObject) ...`

Comment: Do you want to verify if all the properties exist or do you want to return the first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, if any?

Comment: A prop having a value and a prop's value being truthy are too very different things. For example, having `options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.someProp = 0;`  will be not be truthy, even though the prop `someProp` does indeed have a value. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Thank you, I want to verify that they indeed have value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep a reference to `settings`, which improves things a fair bit:

```
const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
    const settings = options.JanrainAppSettings && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings;
    return settings &&
      settings.tokenUrl &&
      settings.capture && // ** This was missing in the question, but I think you need it
      settings.capture.clientId &&
      settings.capture.appId &&
      settings.capture.appDomain &&
      settings.capture.captureServer &&
      settings.httpLoadUrl &&
      settings.httpsLoadUrl;
};
```

While you *could* put some of those names in an array and use a loop, I think I'd leave it at that.

With [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) (new in ES2020), that first line could be:

```
    const settings = options.JanrainAppSettings?.settings;
```

The array version would look something like:

```
const settingsProps = "capture tokenUrl httpLoadUrl httpsLoadUrl".split(" ");
const captureProps = "clientId appId appDomain captureServer".split(" ");
const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
    const settings = options.JanrainAppSettings && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings;
    return settings &&
      settingsProps.every(prop => settings[prop]) &&
      captureProps.every(prop => settings.capture[prop]);
};
```

---

[adiga asks a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077690/how-can-i-check-if-multiple-properties-exists-on-an-object-without-being-too-ver#comment111543904_63077690). If you want existence rather than truthiness (you have truthiness in your question), you'll want `in` (or for an own property check, `hasOwnProperty`). For instance:

```
const settingsProps = "capture tokenUrl httpLoadUrl httpsLoadUrl".split(" ");
const captureProps = "clientId appId appDomain captureServer".split(" ");
const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
    const settings = options.JanrainAppSettings && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings;
    return settings &&
      settingsProps.every(prop => prop in settings) &&
      captureProps.every(prop => prop in settings.capture);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I would opt for an utility function:

```js
function contains(object, ...keys) {
  return keys.every((key) => key in object)
}

const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
  return (
    contains(options.JanrainAppSettings, 'settings') &&
    contains(
      options.JanrainAppSettings.settings,
      'tokenUrl',
      'httpLoadUrl',
      'httpsLoadUrl',
      'capture'
    ) &&
    contains(
      options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture,
      'clientId',
      'appId',
      'appDomain',
      'captureServer'
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Perhaps something like if (['my', 'options'] in  myObject) ...

This is the right idea. However, you need to loop over the array of strings and check if each of them is in `myObject`. You can do this loop with `Array.every()`. The only disadvantage is this only works at the deepest level. Since you have several levels of nesting here it will still get kind of ugly:

```
const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) => {
    return options.JanrainAppSettings
      && options.JanrainAppSettings.settings // dont' forget this check
      && ['tokenUrl', 'httpLoadUrl', 'httpsLoadUrl', 'capture'].every(key => // added options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture check
        key in options.JanrainAppSettings.settings
      )
      && ['clientId', 'appId', 'appDomain', 'captureServer'].every(key =>
        key in options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function that takes a scope and var-arg properties.

```js
const allSet = (scope, ...properties) =>
  scope && (!properties || properties.every(key => !key || key in scope))
```

It would check the scope, along with the presence of all the potential falsy properties.

```js
const sampleOptions = {
  JanrainAppSettings: {
    settings: {
      tokenUrl: '$tokenUrl',
      capture: {
        clientId: '$clientId',
        appId: '$appId',
        appDomain: '$appDomain',
        captureServer: '$captureServer'
      },
      httpLoadUrl: '$httpLoadUrl',
      httpsLoadUrl: '$httpsLoadUrl'
    }
  }
}

const allSet = (scope, ...properties) =>
  scope && (!properties || properties.every(key => !key || key in scope))


const verifyJanrainAppSettings = (options) =>
  allSet(options, 'JanrainAppSettings') &&
  allSet(options.JanrainAppSettings, 'settings') &&
  allSet(options.JanrainAppSettings.settings, 'tokenUrl', 'httpLoadUrl', 'httpsLoadUrl') &&
  allSet(options.JanrainAppSettings.settings.capture, 'clientId', 'appId', 'captureServer')

console.log(verifyJanrainAppSettings(sampleOptions))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a schema-like object that contains all the keys that need to exist in the object and recursively check if an object contains those keys or not using a function like so:

```
const verifyObject = (object, schema) =>
  Object.entries(schema).every(([key, value]) =>
    object && object[key] && (typeof value != "object" || verifyObject(object[key], value))
  );
```

The `object[key]` test will not only verify that the key exists but it will also verify that the value for that key is truthy which may fail the whole test if a value contains a falsy value. If you only want it to check if the key exists, then replace it with `key in object`.

The schema-like object for you `JanrainAppSettings` object is simply an object containing all the keys that needs to exists in a valid `JanrainAppSettings`, the values could be just `0`s or empty strings as they are not needed:

```
const janrainAppSettingsSchema = { JanrainAppSettings: { settings: { capture: { clientId: "", appId: "", appDomain: "", captureServer: "" }, tokenUrl: "", httpLoadUrl: "", httpsLoadUrl: "" } } };
```

So to verify an object, just call `verifyObject` and pass the object and the schema-like object to verify against like so:

```
if(verifyObject(options, janrainAppSettingsSchema)) {
  // everything is ok
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const verifyObject = (object, schema) =>
  Object.entries(schema).every(([key, value]) =>
    object && object[key] && (typeof value != "object" || verifyObject(object[key], value))
  );



let thisWillPass = {
  JanrainAppSettings: {
    settings: {
      capture: {
        clientId: "Id",
        appId: "Id",
        appDomain: "Domain",
        captureServer: "Server"
      },
      tokenUrl: "Url",
      httpLoadUrl: "Url",
      httpsLoadUrl: "Url"
    }
  }
};

let thisWontPass = {
  JanrainAppSettings: {
    settings: {
      capture: {
        clientId: "Id",
        appId: "Id",
        // appDomain: "Domain",
        captureServer: "Server"
      },
      tokenUrl: "Url",
      httpLoadUrl: "Url",
      httpsLoadUrl: "Url"
    }
  }
};

const janrainAppSettingsSchema = { JanrainAppSettings: { settings: { capture: { clientId: "", appId: "", appDomain: "", captureServer: "" }, tokenUrl: "", httpLoadUrl: "", httpsLoadUrl: "" } } };

console.log("Will pass:", verifyObject(thisWillPass, janrainAppSettingsSchema));
console.log("Won't pass:", verifyObject(thisWontPass, janrainAppSettingsSchema));
```